# How can I advertise my app on the App Store?

Tags: app-store-connect

When I released my iOS app on the App Store, how can iPhone user know that this new app is released?

I mean, I do not advertise my app anywhere.

So if my app is already released to App Store, I think no one can know about my newly released app. Is that right?

If they don't know my newly released app, my iOS apps are just useless.
I don't want to advertise with money for my app because I am just a beginner iOS developer. So I don't that much have money.

Is there anyway let user to know about my newly released app without money advertisement?

Answer (score 3):

You can link to apps in the appstore. For example:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinball-arcade/id455826958?mt=8

(This is just a random app I picked to serve as an example)

Now, if you have your link to your app, you can:

- Write a blog about the app and link to it
- Have websites review your app and they will link to it
- Does your app serve the need of a particular community? Maybe they have a forum or mailinglist where you can link to your app and explain the benefits they will get from it.
- Tweet, facebook or Google+ about the app